# An Ant BuildException has occured: unbalanced qoutes

Tags: maven, ant

I get the following error in an Ant file:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (callAppc) on project SalesEdge_CMPD_Session_EJB: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] E:\NetApp-CED\April'15\MyNetApp\MyNetApp\SalesEdge_CMPD_Session_EJB\generateSalesEdgeCmpdSessionEJB.xml:27: unbalanced quotes in  E:\NetApp-CED\April'15\MyNetApp\MyNetApp\SalesEdge_CMPD_Session_EJB\target/SalesEdge_CMPD_Session_EJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<ant antfile="E:\NetApp-CED\April&apos;15\MyNetApp\MyNetApp\SalesEdge_CMPD_Session_EJB/generateSalesEdgeCmpdSessionEJB.xml">... @ 5:127 in E:\NetApp-CED\April'15\MyNetApp\MyNetApp\SalesEdge_CMPD_Session_EJB\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

What is the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue is the quote in April'15

Comment: Thanks a ton @louisa the issue was in the qoutes only